How can I set custom StartupPreferences for a particular Pharo image?
I want a particular image to be run with specific settings at start tiime as noted here
StartupPreferencesLoader default executeAtomicItems: { (StartupAction
             name: 'Start Literate Server'
             code: [
                 | class |
                 class := Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ifAbsent: [
                              Metacello new
                                  baseline: 'LiterateSmalltalk';
                                  repository: 'github://jingtaozf/literate-smalltalk';
                                  onConflict: [ :ex | ex allow ];
                                  load.
                              Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ].
                 class ifNotNil: [ LiterateServer start ] ]
             runOnce: false) }

Is there some way to accomplish this?

You want to custom setting for your application or you want customize setting that is already available in pharo?

@tukan It is a custom setting for a particular image which enables Pharo code to be edited and executed with Emacs. I've found a some tips and tutorial on the process I'm yet to try.

I found on old tutorial that explains the steps Tips and Tricks Booklet from 2017
It involves creating some StartupActions which are executed when the image is loaded.
My need is for start up settings that are specific for particular image and hence are saved in a file in the image's directory rather than the shared preferences directory for Pharo in general or the VM versions shared directory.
| items |
items := OrderedCollection new.
items add: (StartupAction
              name: 'Start Literate Server'
              code: [
                 | class |
                 class := Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ifAbsent: [
                              Metacello new
                                  baseline: 'LiterateSmalltalk';
                                  repository: 'github://jingtaozf/literate-smalltalk';
                                  onConflict: [ :ex | ex allow ];
                                  load.
                              Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ].
                 class ifNotNil: [ LiterateServer start ] ]
              runOnce: false).

StartupPreferencesLoader default
  addAtStartupInImageDirectory: items.

This resulted in a file startup.st having the following contents.
StartupPreferencesLoader default executeAtomicItems: {
    StartupAction name: 'Start Literate Server' code: [ 
                 | class |
                 class := Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ifAbsent: [ 
                              Metacello new
                                  baseline: 'LiterateSmalltalk';
                                  repository: 'github://jingtaozf/literate-smalltalk';
                                  onConflict: [ :ex | ex allow ];
                                  load.
                              Smalltalk at: #LiterateServer ].
                 class ifNotNil: [ LiterateServer start ] ].
}.


I think you maybe better of by creating Emacs keymapping.  I did not play around with it so I don't know how hard it should be.
Here is a quick way to create a new custom settings in Pharo:
First create class for your application:
Object subclass: #VfclistsApplication
    instanceVariableNames: ''
    classVariableNames: 'emacsSetting'
    package: 'VfclistPackage'

First create setter and getter for your variable.
Setter with lazy initialization. This is to prevent the setting being nil.  Your setting must never be nil!
VfclistsApplication class>>emacsSetting
emacsSetting ifNil: [ emacsSetting := false ].
    ^ emacsSetting

getter:
VfclistsApplication class>>emacsSetting: aValue
    emacsSetting := aValue

In the VfclistsApplication class create a method emacsSettingSettingsOn: which defines the setting within your application:
VfclistsApplication class>>emacsSettingSettingsOn: aBuilder
    <systemsettings>
    (aBuilder setting: #emacsSetting)
        target: VfclistsApplication;
        label: 'Emacs setting' translated;
        description: 'A setting needed for the use of Emacs';
        parent: nil.


Is the aBuilder variable an instance of some Builder class?

@vfclists I'm on vacation.Builder is instace of UIBuilder.
